# Why is javascript not recognizing php code?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

*edit: this particular situation was created while I was trying to debug another problem, here's a more thorough description of my problem: [Why is javascript not able to use a javascript variable I declared in a php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526816/why-is-javascript-not-able-to-use-a-javascript-variable-i-declared-in-a-php-file)

Here's the issue:

I've got the following php code within a javascript file but it won't compile. The variable simple is used at the bottom when it's being passed to the function placem:

```
 <?php $simpleString = "i hope this works"; ?>


 var simple = "<?php echo $simpleString; ?>";

 window['mod0_2']= -.0015138;
 window['mod1_2']= -.3424094;
 window['mod2_2']= .40461099;

 window['lla0_2']= 43.6124872;
 window['lla1_2']= -116.20349;
 window['lla2_2']= 821.802867;

 window['publica2'] = new modd('milktruck','publica2',modScaler,'shadowrect3',1);

 placem('p2','pp2', simple, window['lla0_2'],window['lla1_2'],window['lla2_2']);
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What does the output look like?

Comment: Is the php code parsed at all? If you save it as a .js file a standard-configured web server might not parse it.

Comment: Are you executing the javascript code on a browser, or in a tool like [v8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) or [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) on your server? You _do_ know that no mainstream browser comes with a PHP interpreter, right?

Comment: Do you have the js file set up to be parsed as php (either using a `.php` extension or by adding php handling for js files to the webserver config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical scenario is to have HTML, JavaScript and PHP (or some other server side programming language/technology) hosted on a server.  You would then access the website using a web browser from another machine.  Again, this the *typical* scenario.  All these components can exist on the same machine.

In the opensource world, the most popular web server is called Apache.  There is a module for Apache (called mod_php) which interprets PHP code, executes it and returns its output.  (Modules do exist for other programming languages, but I won't get into that.)

There are two basic approaches to what you'd like to accomplish, both have their pros and cons.

1) Configure mod_php to interpret *.js files as if they were PHP files.

2) Create your JavaScript files as PHP files.  This is the same way that HTML is served from PHP files.  The PHP code can be mixed in with HTML in the same file.  The tag `<?php ... ?>` specifies the PHP code that should be interpreted by mod_php.  Everything else is just sent to the browser as output.

Here is a very simple example of a very simply HTML page, with PHP used to provide the content of the `<title>` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

That would appear in a PHP file on the server.  In the browser, the resulting HTML source would look like the following. (That is, if you did a "view source" on the page.  The page itself would appear blank and the title bar would contain the words: Hello world.)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Hello world
</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This can also be done with JavaScript instead of HTML.  The important thing to keep in mind is that there are two views of this file.  One, is what you see when looking at the raw file.  The other is how that file looks after the PHP is executed and output is returned to the browser.  What you are basically doing is combining output from PHP with HTML/JavaScript to form the final output that is sent to the browser for display.

Comment: A note about this: based on another question you've asked, I see that you're using a GoDaddy account.  I'm pretty sure that means you don't have access to configure Apache to interpret JavaScript source files as PHP.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using PHP in a .js file? If so, Javascript runs on client side where PHP runs on server. If you want to execute PHP in a Javascript file, you have to rename that file to .php and include that new PHP file into your HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by include the php file into the html? Which file do I rename to .php , the javascript file? So would I rename milktruck.js to milktruck.php and delete the old milktruck.js?

Comment: @user671891: If you need PHP code to be interpreted in a `.js` file then you'll either need to configure your web server to run `.js` files through the PHP interpreter before serving them to the client, or simply rename the `.js` file to a `.php` file.  The former is more complicated, the latter is less intuitive to support.

Comment: Yes, rename that milktruck.js to milktruck.php if you want to execute PHP in a .js file. Than include <script src="milktruck.php"></script>

Comment: In my html file I have the following call to my javascript file: <script type="text/javascript" src="milktruck.js"></script> and in my javascript file there are no <script> tags. What would I have to do in that situation to implement your latter suggestion?

Comment: Did you try <script src="milktruck.php"></script> ?

Answer (score 1):

milktruck.php

```
<?php 
 $simpleString = "i hope this works"; 

echo 'var simple = "'.$simpleString.'";

 window[\'mod0_2\']= -.0015138;
 window[\'mod1_2\']= -.3424094;
 window[\'mod2_2\']= .40461099;

 window[\'lla0_2\']= 43.6124872;
 window[\'lla1_2\']= -116.20349;
 window[\'lla2_2\']= 821.802867;

 window[\'publica2\'] = new modd(\'milktruck\',\'publica2\',modScaler,\'shadowrect3\',1);

 placem(\'p2\',\'pp2\', simple, window[\'lla0_2\'],window[\'lla1_2\'],window[\'lla2_2\']);';

?>


<script src="milktruck.php"></script>
```

you could make use of htaccess and keep the .js extension by having some modrewrites

Comment: Why would you simply not just break out of PHP mode with a `?>` before doing that hideously long text block? It would save you have to escape every single quote in there. Just because you can output text with a PHP print/echo doesn't mean you SHOULD. If you instant on doing that sort of thing in PHP, at least use a HEREDOC.